# Script is only showing one result how can I output all the results inside a p tag?

Tags: javascript

I have this script that gets all the attributes and its values and outputs them on the page. The problem I am having is it's currently working with `document.write` but I want to put the results inside a `p` tag. When I try to do that it only shows one attribute and its value. How can I output all the attributes and its values inside the targeted `p` tag?

My code

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo'),
    attrs = foo.attributes,
    i = attrs.length,
    attr;

while (i--)
{
    attr = attrs[i];
    document.write(attr.name + '="' + attr.value + '"');
    /*document.querySelector('p').innerHTML= attr.name + '="' + attr.value + '"'; <-- This method only shows one attribute and its value :(*/
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="bar baz" style="margin-left: 2px; height: 10px;"></div>

<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should construct whole string and write to `<p>` once.

```
var content = [];
while (i--)
{
attr = attrs[i];
content.push(attr.name + '="' + attr.value + '"');
}
document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = content.join(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a string inside the while loop and assign that string to innerHTML after the loop.

Comment: Can you provide a code example actually this is an example I found online not really my code